# windows 8 store app - dependency issue - certification failed

Tags: windows-8

We just submitted app in windows 8 store (metro style app) and got the error:

`XXX takes a dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package framework but is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest.`

We had our app working fine in release version but it was not getting accepted as package so we needed to migrate our app as Windows RTM. During that we had following entry 
in manifest:

```
    <Dependencies>
        <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.110"       MinVersion="11.0.0.0" />
    </Dependencies>
```

If we keep this, we get following error while build the app.

```
Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package 5d6f272d-c915-4de1-a9d6-c0c08d63ab94 because 
this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 11.0.50727.1 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.110 
published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package. (0x80073cf3) Test_App1
```

So we removed it and submit the app, it just got failed and gave following error.

```
XXXX takes a dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package framework but is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest.
```

We need to keep this package itself in the manifest but not getting it done.

Comment: The issue got resolved by updating <Dependencies>
        <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.110"       MinVersion="11.0.0.0" />
    </Dependencies> to

<Dependencies>
        <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00"       MinVersion="11.0.0.0" />
    </Dependencies>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved by updating

"Microsoft.VCLibs.110" to Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00"

Comment: This article explains what Microsoft.VCLibs means for Windows Store apps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem.
Add a reference in your project to `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package`

Just click on project i select Add reference and find this Package. Adding this should resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just I've repaired the VS 2012 for windows 8 from Control panel > Programs and the designer works fine.